# Problems with token expired in Bluemix

Tags: cloud, ibm, bluemix

I have a recurrent problem when try create a container's group:

The exact message is:

```
INFO: 2017/03/23 15:50:19 Auth Error: {
    "code": "IC5029E",
    "description": "Your access token is expired. Run 'cf ic init' to refresh your access token.",
    "environment": "prod-dal09",
    "host_id": "177",
    "incident_id": "3494-1490302258.491-1326411",
    "name": "ExpiredToken",
    "rc": "401",
    "type": "Authorization"
}
FAILED
A problem occurred with the login. Your session might have expired. Use "cf ic login" to log in again.
```

I executed:

`cf ic login` and after `cf ic init` but the problem persist.

Thanks

Comment: I'm having a similar problem quite frustrating